# How to create a writeablebitmap image from an image file in windows8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, writeablebitmap

I want to load an image file from local disk to a writeablebitmap image, so I can let users to edit it. when I create a WriteableBitmap object, the constructor need pixelwidth and pixelheight parameters, I don't know where to get these two, anyone can help?

Comment: How do you load the image from file?

Comment: But I guess you load the image through a **BitmapImage** or something like that and **then** you create a **WriteableBitmap**, right?

Comment: Yes, I want to load the file and then convert it to writeablebitmap. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't care the pixelWidth and pixelHeight when define the WriteableBitmap image, please try this:

```
using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    WriteableBitmap image = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
    image.SetSource(stream);
    WriteableBitmapImage.Source = image;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code. There is an straightforward way to do this (load the image using *BitmapImage* and then pass this object directly to *WriteableBitmap* constructor, but I'm not sure if this works as expected or it has performance problem, don't remember):

```
BitmapSource bmp = BitmapFrame.Create(
    new Uri(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg", UriKind.Relative),
    BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);

if (bmp.Format != PixelFormats.Bgra32)
    bmp = new FormatConvertedBitmap(bmp, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null, 1);
    // Just ignore the last parameter

WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight,
    kbmp.DpiX, bmp.DpiY, bmp.Format, bmp.Palette);

Int32Rect r = new Int32Rect(0, 0, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight);
wbmp.Lock();
bmp.CopyPixels(r, wbmp.BackBuffer, wbmp.BackBufferStride * wbmp.PixelHeight,
    wbmp.BackBufferStride);

wbmp.AddDirtyRect(r);
wbmp.Unlock();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have the correct pixel width and height, you need to load it into a BitmapImage first to populate it correctly:

```
StorageFile storageFile =
    await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync("ms-appx:///myimage.png");
using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
{
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);

    WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap =
        new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage.PixelWidth, bitmapImage.PixelHeight);
    fileStream.Seek(0);
    await writeableBitmap.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
}
```

(For WinRT apps)